# How to set Frame rate for video capture by camera in android...?

Tags: android, video-capture

Actually I want to get video capture by camera of frame rate 30 from android device, but it changes according different devices.
So How can I set or restrict video capture by camera to frame rate of 30.
I've tried (MediaRecorder) **recorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)**, but it doesn't make any changes in capturing video..

Thank a lot in advance...!!:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely does change the frame rate of the recorded video.  I just did a test on Xoom running Ice Cream Sandwich and without setting that value it defaulted to about 8fps.  It's possible that the device you're using doesn't support the frame rate you're attempting (I used 24).

Make SURE you're following the documented instructions as to WHEN you make this call. It explicitly says you need to do after setting the format but before calling prepare.

The camera will simply ignore your setting if it can't handle the settings.

Answer (score -1):

setCaptureRate() will help set the capture rate!